# Connect firewire MacMini to thunderbolt MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, mac-mini, thunderbolt, firewire

I have a MacMini that only has a firewire port, I want to connect it to my MacBook Pro via its thunderbolt port, can I do this so that I can then (using target mode) display my Mac mini on my macbook pro)? What equipment would I need todo this?

Answer (score 1):

You would need a Apple Thunderbolt to FireWire Adapter.

You can find it [here for $29](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MD464ZM/A/apple-thunderbolt-to-firewire-adapter)

Please also read this.

[Apple's Thunderbolt FireWire adapter can connect to Macs via both ends, but can only be used in one direction.](http://www.cnet.com/news/apples-thunderbolt-firewire-adapter-is-a-one-way-connector/)