# How to display non-DV video signal with Firewire input?

Tags: thunderbolt, hdmi, displayport, video-adapter, firewire

Is there any way to get the video signal output from a Displayport (mDP) or Thunderbolt (1 / 2) socket into a Firewire (FW800, IEEE 1394) input? What cables, adapters and drivers or other software would I need?

I do have an mDP 1.2 to [hdmi](/questions/tagged/hdmi)/[dvi](/questions/tagged/dvi)/[vga](/questions/tagged/vga) adapter if that helps. So the question may be reduced to: How do I get a Firewire input to accept and display a monitor video signal instead of either a DV camera signal or a Firewire Target Display Mode signal?

### Related questions

- [Connect firewire MacMini to thunderbolt MacBook Pro](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/151521/connect-firewire-macmini-to-thunderbolt-macbook-pro) (other way around – solution: 1-way TB-FW adapter)
- [Is it possible to set up an old iMac as an external monitor without Target Display Mode?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/188222/is-it-possible-to-set-up-an-old-imac-as-an-external-monitor-without-target-displ?rq=1) (basically the same question without enough details)
- [How to use an old iMac as an external display for a MacBook via wifi?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206044/how-to-use-an-old-imac-as-an-external-display-for-a-macbook-via-wifi) (similar question but focussing on software solutions)

Comment: Can you give us a little more info? What display are you using? What computer? Why do you need to use Firewire? Can you use another port?

Comment: @JMY1000 The “display” is an old iMac, unfortunately also without support for Target Display Mode. Firewire is its only free input port. The third of the linked questions deals with network solutions.

Comment: If that's the case, there's no way you'll be able to use the display directly without using either some sort of software like [Synergy](http://synergy-project.org/) or ripping the display out.

Comment: I was hoping for some exotic piece of hard or software that converted a screen/monitor signal (DP, DVI, HDMI, VGA) into a camera/recording signal (DV).

Comment: Possible, but none that I know of.